# Using PDO and LIKE not working, why?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to connect to MySQL. Everything is working fine, except this doesn't work.

Does anyone knows why? And how should i do it?

```
SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE :flagids LIKE CONCAT('%', flagIt.flagIt_id, '%')
```

:flagids is equivalent to a string like "ID1 ID2 ID3".

EDIT (just to compare)

```
SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE 'ID1 ID2 ID3' LIKE CONCAT('%', flagIt.flagIt_id, '%)
```

If i use like this, it works fine, so...why it does not work with :flagids?

I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you very much.

EDIT

I tried:

```
"SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE flagIt.flagIt_id IN(:flagids)"
```

and as Hobo Sapiens suggested

```
"SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE FIND_IN_SET(flagIt.flagIt_id, :flagids)"
```

and nothing works!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can't use a bound variable for an identifier

Comment: @HoboSapiens i added a comparison with a way that works.

Comment: @HoboSapiens maybe I have not understood your comment (I am not an expert), but do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you're submitting to PDO::prepare():

```
SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE :flagids LIKE CONCAT('%', flagIt.flagIt_id, '%')
```

The process of preparing a statement doesn't just involve evaluating the contents of the placeholders, substituting them in a string and executing the resulting query.

A `prepare` asks the server to evaluate the query and prepare an execution plan that includes the table and indexes it will use. For that it needs to know which columns of which tables it must work with, which is why one cannot use a placeholder where you would need an identifier.

The problem with your query is that the server has no way to know at the time it prepares the statement whether the placeholder represents a string literal or a column identifier. Without that information, the preparation cannot be done, and your `prepare` will fail.

If you have some flexibility over the value you're using in `:flagids` you could use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT * FROM flagIt WHERE find_in_set(flagIt_id, :flagids)
```

where a variable containing, for example, `'ID1,ID2,ID3'` is bound to `:flagids`.

This will be fine for small lists, but will be slow for a large list.

[MySQL reference for  find_in_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: i tried different methods as i say in question (EDITED)  but it doesn't work ...what is the problem now? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you haven't posted the PHP code that handled this query so it's possible that there is a problem there.